# php mysql insert from array item

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

my array item structure look like

```
title: "",
createdBy: "",
pointerSet:[
    {position: 1, catagoryId: 1, caption: "", imageUrl: ""}
    {position: 1, catagoryId: 1, caption: "", imageUrl: ""}
    {position: 1, catagoryId: 1, caption: "", imageUrl: ""}

]
```

Now if my URL hit with this item array data then how can i insert pointerSet array item in database.

my database data goes to two table

table one

```
title: "",
createdBy: "",
```

then table two

```
pointerSet:[
    {position: 1, catagoryId: 1, caption: "", imageUrl: ""}
    {position: 1, catagoryId: 1, caption: "", imageUrl: ""}
    {position: 1, catagoryId: 1, caption: "", imageUrl: ""}

]
```

I am using get method.

in  table one i can insert but for table two how can i insert .

```
$_GET['pointerSet'] = array(
  array(position='', catagoryId='',caption='',imageUrl=''),
  array(position='', catagoryId='',caption='',imageUrl=''),
  array(position='', catagoryId='',caption='',imageUrl='')
);
```

Comment: Use a loop that inserts a row for each pointer in the pointer set.

Comment: please give example @Barmar

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can do it using a PDO prepared statement

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO pointerTable (position, categoryid, caption, imageurl) VALUES(:position, :categoryid, :caption, :imageurl)");
foreach ($array['pointerSet'] as $pointer) {
    $stmt->execute($pointer);
}
```